# Image swapping using JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to swap images using `JavaScript`. When only `section1` is used the swapping of image works but when `section2` is added then the swapping of image works only on `section2`(stops swapping in `section1`).

Codes are:

**JavaScript**
`--section1--`

```
var imagetracker="m";
function change(){
var image=document.getElementById('image1');
if(imagetracker=="m"){
    image.src="images/momo 2.jpg";
    imagetracker="t";
}else if(imagetracker=='t'){
    image.src="images/taco.jpg";
    imagetracker="m";
}
}
var timer = setInterval('change()',2000);
```

`--section2--`

```
var imagetracker="p2";
function change2(){
var image=document.getElementById('image2');
if(imagetracker=="p2"){
    image.src="images/pizza 2.jpg";
    imagetracker="b";
}else if(imagetracker=='b'){
    image.src="images/burrito 2.jpg";
    imagetracker="p2";
}
}
var timer2 = setInterval('change2()',2000);
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="images/momo 2.jpg" height="150" width="220" id="image1">
<img src="images/pizza 2.jpg" height="150" width="220" id="image2"><p>
```

How should be done to make `section1` work?

Comment: `setInterval(change, 2000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `imagetracker` variables. Rename either one so that there is one of each.

You assign `imagetracker` to `"m"` and `"p2"` which will cause an error because there are two defined variables of the same name.

You can change the `setInterval` lines to:

```
var timer = setInterval(change, 2000);
```

This gives the function as a parameter and sets the interval to run `change()` every 2 seconds. This also applies to the second timer.

Your version is fine and strings are fine to be passed as functions.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) is a reference on the `setInterval` function from W3Schools

Comment: @Andrew L. Thank you for your great effort! It finally solved the problem. Now the images are swapping perfectly.

Comment: No problem! If you need anything else, just ask!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using same `imagetracker` variable for both, it may cause problem since values are different. So use different variables for both, that may fix your problem.

```js
var imagetracker = "m";

function change() {
  var image = document.getElementById('image1');
  if (imagetracker == "m") {
    image.src = "images/momo 2.jpg";
    imagetracker = "t";
  } else if (imagetracker == 't') {
    image.src = "images/taco.jpg";
    imagetracker = "m";
  }
}
var timer = setInterval('change()', 2000);

var imagetracker1 = "p2";

function change2() {
  var image = document.getElementById('image2');
  if (imagetracker1 == "p2") {
    image.src = "images/pizza 2.jpg";
    imagetracker1 = "b";
  } else if (imagetracker1 == 'b') {
    image.src = "images/burrito 2.jpg";
    imagetracke1r = "p2";
  }
}
var timer2 = setInterval('change2()', 2000);
```

```html
<img src="images/momo 2.jpg" height="150" width="220" id="image1">
<img src="images/pizza 2.jpg" height="150" width="220" id="image2">
<p>
```

---

Also instead of the string param [you can use function reference as argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#Syntax), that may be much better way to do it.

```
var timer2 = setInterval(change, 2000);
```

---

**FYI :** String of code is not recommenced because that have lot of security problems, since it's working using **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**.

Refer  : [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Too unscalable code.
Let's try fix it :)

```
function rotImg(id, urls) {
  var img = document.getElementById(id);
  var index = -1;
  return function() {
    if (++index >= urls.length) index = 0;
    img.src = urls[index];
  };
}
setInterval(rotImg('image1', [
  'images/momo 2.jpg', 
  'images/taco.jpg'
]), 2000);
setInterval(rotImg('image2', [
  'images/pizza 2.jpg', 
  'images/burrito 2.jpg'
]), 2000);
```

```js
function rotImg(id, urls) {
  var img = document.getElementById(id);
  var index = -1;
  return function() {
    if (++index >= urls.length) index = 0;
    img.src = urls[index];
  };
}
setInterval(rotImg('image1', [
  'https://placekitten.com/200/300',
  'https://placekitten.com/200/301',
  'https://placekitten.com/201/300'
]), 2000);
setInterval(rotImg('image2', [
  'https://placekitten.com/300/200',
  'https://placekitten.com/300/201',
  'https://placekitten.com/301/200'
]), 2000);
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/201/300" height="220" id="image1">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/301/200" height="220" id="image2">
```

Comment: I tried to run your code but the images aren't swapping.

Comment: Thanks for snippet, I've changed images to kittens :)